# Save data to text

Tags: powerapps

I made a small app to generate provisioning scripts. It is using 2 related SharePoint lists like: sitemodule (moduleid, name) -> (moduleid, powershell commands) For every module belongs multiple ps commands like create site, apply template, upload files etc. 
I can fill a textbox with the generated scripts, and copy-paste from there, but would be nicer if I could save the box content as text file (local, sharepoint, onedrive, doesn't matter). The "export" control is not suitable for this, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flows for doing this, you can send to Flows the filename and the content of it to create it in Sharepoint.

Take a look to this post that explains it very well:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-from-powerapps-using-flow/